# Convert map to list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What is the list comprehension expression that would accomplish the same thing as:

```
seq_len = list(map(len, fasta_file.readlines()))
```

Comment: `[x for x in list(map(len, fasta_file.readlines()))]`

Comment: What is the dictionary comprehension equivalent to the following code?Can you please help me in this? human_sp = {} for record in sp_records: if record.id.find("HUMAN") > -1: human_sp[record.id] = record

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `readlines`. A file is iterable.

You are mapping the len function, so you call it over the elements

```
[len(line) for line in fasta_file]
```

Comment: What about map? Do I need to store anything on map?

Comment: `map` is a function, not something you store anything in

Comment: Okay, got it. I am new to Python. Can you please share me some link where I can Python thoroughly.

Comment: @puneeth There's a whole Tutorial on the official Python website

Comment: @Anton the question doesn't do it

Comment: What is the dictionary comprehension equivalent to the following code?Can you please help me in this?                                                 
                                                                                                    
human_sp = {}
for record in sp_records:
   if record.id.find("HUMAN") > -1:
      human_sp[record.id] = record

Comment: True but seeing he is a novice strip is normally something you want to do

Comment: @AntonvBR  What is strip

Comment: Read about str strip. It removes white space and rowbreaks before and after string.

Comment: @AntonvBR                                                                                         
What is the dictionary comprehension equivalent to the following code?Can you please help me in this?                                                 
                                                                                                    
human_sp = {}
for record in sp_records:
   if record.id.find("HUMAN") > -1:
      human_sp[record.id] = record

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. @puneeth Don't rewrite the question.

Comment: @puneeth Don't think everything can be written in one line. Never sacrifice logical understanding or clarity for conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
seq_len = list(map(len, f.readlines()))
```

is same as:

```
print([len(i) for i in f.readlines()])
```

You are mapping each item(line) of file to len it means you are just calculating the length of each item and from that logic you can just iterate over the lines of file and calculate the len of the item.

so you can do like:

```
print([len(i) for i in f.readlines()])
```